# Signing custom compiled kernel for Secure Boot

Tags: kernel, uefi, secure-boot, self-signed

I am following steps given [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/KeyManagement/KeyGeneration) to generate keys in order to sign a copy of kernel I compiled myself. However, midway through the process, when I try to verify that "the master certificate is signed with its private key" by running

```
$ openssl verify ./master-public.pem
```

it fails with the following output:

```
C = GB, ST = Isle of Man, L = Douglas, O = Canonical Ltd., CN = Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority
error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self signed certificate
error ./master-public.pem: verification failed
```

The expected output according to documentation is:

```
./master-public.pem: C = GB, ST = Isle of Man, L = Douglas, O = Canonical Ltd., CN = Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
```

As is probably obvious, I am not an expert in Secure Boot related shenanigans, and have spent quite a while trying to figure out what's wrong without any leads. The webpage mentioned above doesn't give provide any help either.

Can some one tell me why this error might be happening, and how to fix it? Are the instructions on Ubunutu's Wiki obsolete? If yes, are there any up-to-date instructions available? All I want to do is compile and run a copy of `staging` kernel with Secure Boot on.

Answer (score 1):

The steps given [here](https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface/blob/3267e4ea1f318bb9716d6742d79162de8277dea2/SIGNING.md) actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with

- building my own kernel with   `make bindep-pkg` from vanilla TGZ from https://kernel.org
- booting it with kexec

So no signing is needed: UEFI boots officially signed Ubuntu kernel, then  my custom kernel is loaded from Linux userspace as cron `@reboot` task.